# How To Fix This Error : Cannot destructure property 'handleLogout' of '(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: next.js, client-server, react-context, react-server-components

## I have this page, which is a context api that provides login status and some other functions

```
"use client";
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
export const LoginContext = createContext();

export const LoginProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const [post, setPost] = useState("");
  const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(["token"]);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    setPost({ ...post, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3001/auth/login", post)
      .then((response) => {
        const { data } = response;
        setCookie("token", data.access_token, { path: "/" });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setErrorMessage("Incorrect password or username");
      });

  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoggedIn(!!cookies.token);
  }, [cookies]);

  const handleLogout = () => {
    removeCookie("token", { path: "/" });
  };

  return (
    <LoginContext.Provider value={{ handleLogout, isLoggedIn, errorMessage, handleSubmit, handleInput }}>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </LoginContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

## **And I have this layout page

## **

```
import "./globals.css";
import  Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";
import { Footer } from "@/components/Footer";
import { LoginProvider } from "@/context/LoginContext";

export const metadata = {
  title: "Mox Movies",
  description: "Explore Latest Movies",
};


export default function RootLayout({children}) {
  
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className="relative">
        <div className="container flex flex-col justify-between min-h-screen min-w-[1360px] my-0 mx-auto">
        <Navbar />
            <LoginProvider>
              <div>
          {children}
              </div>
            </LoginProvider>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

## And the last thing I have is this navbar page

```
"use client";

import React, { useContext } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import {
  CustomButtonGreen,
  CustomButtonaBlack,
  links,
  SearchBar,
} from "@/components/data";
import { LoginContext } from "@/context/LoginContext";

const Navbar = () => {
  const { handleLogout, isLoggedIn } = useContext(LoginContext);



  return (
    <header className="grid grid-cols-3 p-10 items-center">
      <Link
        href="/"
        className="font-medium text-xl md:text:sm italic bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-gradient-to-t from-slate-100 to-lime-400"
      >
        MOX MOVIES
      </Link>
      <div className=" flex justify-center md:gap-9 items-center">
        {links.map((link) => (
          <Link key={link.id} href={link.url} className={link.class}>
            {link.title}
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="flex justify-end gap-3 items-center">
        <SearchBar placeholder="Search for Movie..." />

        {isLoggedIn ? (
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="bg-lime-500 text-black p-t-3 rounded-md px-3 py-2 font-medium"
              onClick={handleLogout}
            >
              Log Out
            </button>
        ) : (
          <>
            <CustomButtonGreen href="/auth/login">Sign In</CustomButtonGreen>
            <CustomButtonaBlack href="/auth/register">
              Sign Up
            </CustomButtonaBlack>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

I want to fix this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'handleLogout' of '(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined.

Source

components\Navbar.jsx (14:10) @ handleLogout

  12 |
  13 | const Navbar = () => {
 14 | const { handleLogout, isLoggedIn } = useContext(LoginContext);
```

I don't know why this error always accompanies me. I have tried a lot to fix it, but to no avail. Please help

## I tried to use the context api without 'use client' but I got this error :

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Cannot access _context.Consumer on the server. You cannot dot into a client module from a server component. You can only pass the imported name through.

Source
components\Navbar.jsx (13:50) @ LoginContext

  11 |
  12 | const Navbar = () => {
 13 | const { handleLogout, isLoggedIn } = useContext(LoginContext);
```